# How to insert date into YYYY-MM-DD plain text into Google Spreadsheet with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Essentially I would like to have a YYYY-MM-DD format inserted into a cell on a new spreadsheet when it is created as plain text. The trouble is that when the inserted value is inserted into the new sheet it appears as DD/MM/YYYY which is unreadable by the other program that is running in the background.

Here is the following code:

```
function dateTest() 
{
var template = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC------1234')
var test = template.getSheetByName('TEST');
var database = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DASHBOARD');

//start & endDates are in YYYY-MM-DD format in these cells
var startDate = database.getRange('A10').getValue();
var endDate = database.getRange('A11').getValue();

//The results come up as DD/MM/YYYY when they are set into TEST
//Formatted to YYYY-MM-DD has already been done 
test.getRange('D1').setValue(startDate);
test.getRange('D2').setValue(endDate);

}
```

If necessary, the date could be split into YYYY + '-' + 'MM' + '-' + 'DD' and then inserted as plain text, however I am clueless as to how to perform this feat. Any advise would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the "other programm" you mention ? is it also GAS ?

Comment: No, fortunately I had found an answer for this question if it were GAS. But thank you for asking! @Serge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be cleaned up but here are the basics.

```
//start & endDates are in YYYY-MM-DD format in these cells
var startDate = database.getRange('A10').getValue();
var strStartDate = startDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + startDate.getDate();
var endDate = database.getRange('A11').getValue();
var strEndDate = endDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (endDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + endDate.getDate();

//The results come up as DD/MM/YYYY when they are set into TEST
//Formatted to YYYY-MM-DD has already been done 
test.getRange('D1').setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
test.getRange('D1').setValue(strStartDate);

test.getRange('D2').setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
test.getRange('D2').setValue(strEndDate);
```

Comment: The date strings with single digit months or days will be formatted wrong:   try other solutions in this post or: ---   to.setValue(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1 + 100).toString().slice(1,2) + "-" + (date.getDate() + 100).toString().slice(1,2));

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'm assuming you don't have to set the format as anything in particular. Thank you @ScampMichael !

Answer (score 3):

In Google Spreadsheets, a leading apostrophe means ignore formatting. Thus, this works:

```
range.setValue("'2007-09-12");
```

Alternatively, the text can be quotes and set as a "formula":

```
range.setFormula('"2007-09-12"');
```

(Make sure the string includes double quotes not single quotes - Apps Script is JavaScript and therefore supports either, but spreadsheet formulas don't understand single quotes the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround: in the sheet manually set a cell format to "Plain Text" that is not involved in the operation. Let's call this cell J1. Now before calling:

```
test.getRange('D1').setValue(startDate);
test.getRange('D2').setValue(endDate);
```

Do something like:

```
test.getRange('J1').copyFormatToRange(test,3,3,0,1); // This is D1 and D2
test.getRange('D1').setValue(startDate);
test.getRange('D2').setValue(endDate);
```

This should let you have clear text format on destination cells.

Comment: This also returned DD/MM/YYYY even though the format was set as YYYY-MM-DD. I assume the problem lies with A10 and A11 because they are being read from a date database which corresponds to a week number. @Marcello I have tried to do a circular test, but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

This will reformat the date and set it as string:

```
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(startDate, tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // Requested format
  s.getRange('D1').setValue("'" + newDate);  // Set as string
```

Comment: I received an error message: `TypeError: Cannot find function getSpreadsheetTimeZone` Is there something that I'm doing wrong? @BryanP

Comment: `ss` in my code is the active spreadsheet you're reading the date from, so just add in `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` near the top.